# How to set onListItemClick on ListView id isn't android.R.list

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have few listView on my application. I want to set onListItemClick on every Listview. first listView used id android.R.list so no problem on that. But i stuck on other ListView, because android.R.list already used and i can't use it anymore. So i use different id like android.R.list1 and android.R.list2. But i can't set onListItemClick on List1 and List2. My application always force stop and log said i must have ListView with id android.R.list. How to fix it ? Any idea ?

Thanks...

this my main_layout xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android1:id="@+id/textHint"
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:text="Tap to subscribe channel"
        android1:textAlignment="center"
        android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listAvailableChannel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

And this is i set listview adapter

    CustomListAvailableChannels adapter = new
      CustomListAvailableChannels(AvailableChannelActivity.this, channel_id,channel_img, channel_name);
      listAvailableChannel=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listAvailableChannel);
      listAvailableChannel.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can you add your code ?

Comment: Which one ? XML Layout or Activity

Comment: your lists in `xml` and the part of `code` that you find and set onClicklistener for your list

Answer (score 0):

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShopDetails.class);


                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

I think You can try this way...

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't know why, i try your code and not work. Maybe because i used custom view adapter.